# How to connect Kyvos cube (Bigdata Cube) in Excel?

Tags: bigdata, cube, olap-cube

> How to connect Kyvos cube (Bigdata Cube) in Excel

Answer (score 2):

Open Excel -> Data -> Get Data -> From Database -> From Analysis Services

URL to enter in server Name (sample url): https://kyvospreprod.xyzcompany.com:2443/kyvos/xmlaKyvos

[image]